# MySQL Command executing, but C# program hangs infinitely

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I am creating a MySqlCommand object using a connection string (confirmed to be correct) and executing it via `ExecuteNonQueryAsync()`. The command is definitely executing, as I can see the connection and command when I run `show processlist` in MySQL Workbench.

However, my program hangs infinitely at this step. I have put breakpoints before and after, and the after never activates. I have set the CommandTimeout to 10 seconds in this instance, and the execution does not timeout at this stage.

My minimum example:

```
MySqlCommand command2 = new MySqlCommand("DO SLEEP(20)", connection);
command2.CommandTimeout = 10;
await command2.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
Console.WriteLine(); //Never Activates
```

Just wondering where I can look to try and debug this?

Comment: Look further up your call stack for any blocking code ( `.Wait()`, `.Result`, or `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`).

Comment: Hi @Harry Adams,
I have a few comments, let see if works
1. you are using ```ExecuteNonQueryAsync()``` , I assume that, you also use ```Async``` Method.
2. Instead of using ```DO SLEEP(20)``` , try ```Select Sysdate()``` since you just want to check the DB connection 
I hope, it can help you.

Comment: Use the "Break All" button in the debugger, and check what the threads are doing, especially the Main thread. Chances are you have a deadlock due to the main thread blocking on the task returned by the dbQuery.

Comment: this is just a hunch to see if something is the case, but: can you try adding `var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(command2);` before the `await` (and optionally, `handle.Free();` after the `await`), and see if it still does that? If this fixes it, it is a `MySql` ADO.NET provider bug, but I'll happily explain what the cause is...

Comment: @StephenCleary nothing above the call stack, the program is definitely hanging on ExecuteNonQueryAsync()

Comment: @ThomasLee The command itself is irrelevant, but I needed something that would run long enough to check in the Workbench - and the connection does appear and execute.

Comment: @MarcGravell No fix unfortunately!

Comment: Sorry @StephenCleary just reread and seen `.Result` - I think I've async'd this incorrectly as it is a .Result called, do you know what I need to do? I can't mark the calling method async as it's part of an interface, but the method being called is only Async.

Comment: @HarryAdams: the proper solution is to make the interface method async. There are [some hack solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development), too; the one most likely to work here is `Task.Run(async code).GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, but note that will block the UI thread (if this is a UI app), which is considered a poor user experience.

Comment: @MarcGravell: I'm curious to hear details, if you have a blog post / issue. I work with the primary maintainer of the unofficial MySqlConnector that most folks use; he may be interested, too.

Comment: @StephenCleary I was wondering if this was (for example) a TCS that wasn't rooted (perhaps via a weak-ref somewhere), causing the entire async state machinery to get collected. I ... might have been bitten hard by this in one of my own libraries :)